# Send mail to Document Library in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sendmail, document-library

I have 1 document Library I want to send email with attachment to that Library.for which email Id I want to send Email.

Comment: Ok, just go ahead and do it. Or do you have any particular question? Then please share with us and show us what you've already done.

Comment: I have create 1 document Library & configure email Incoming email settings.

Comment: I can't see a question again. If you want help, you have to learn to express your question in a better manner.

Comment: Hi Sarika, please read our [how to ask guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) this will help us help you, as of now, I agree with ckruczek that there is no question!

Comment: sharepoint.stackexchange.com is better suited for this kind of question

Answer (score 1):

Did you go through these links ..

[Configure incoming e-mail - Central Administration](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262775%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[Enable and configure e-mail settings for a library](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-and-configure-e-mail-support-for-a-list-or-library-dcaf44a0-1d9b-451a-84c7-6c52e7db908e)

You need to enter unique name to use as part of the e-mail address in library setting.